# Subtotals based on specific columns in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could anyone suggest the query for the below scenario?

Table is as below

```
MachineName ManufacturedBy Amount
---------------------------------
A              X            50
B              X            50
C              Q            30
D              Q            30
```

The data should be as follows

```
  MachineName ManufacturedBy Amount
  ----------------------------------
    A              X            50
    B              X            50
    Subtotal                   100

    C              Q            30
    D              Q            30
    Subtotal                    60

    Grandtotal
```

Thanks

Sasi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below. It also worked for me.

SELECT
    ManufacturedBy ,
    MachineName  ,
    SUM AS Amount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (ManufacturedBy,(ManufacturedBy, MachineName),());

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may use `GROUP BY` with `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(ManufacturedBy, 'All Manufacturers') AS ManufacturedBy,
    COALESCE(MachineName, 'All Machines') AS MachineName,
    SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ROLLUP (ManufacturedBy, MachineName);
```

### Demo

Comment: It is fine if I want grouping for one column but what if there are nmore than one column.

Comment: I have answered your question.  If you had another query in mind, you should have asked that instead.  To your question, you may add any number of columns to the `GROUP BY` clause.